# Does having two or more calls to scope_identity() in a single procedure work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Does having 2 or more calls to `scope_identity()` in a single procedure work?

For example:

```
declare @id_1 as int
declare @id_2 as int

insert into table_1 (...) 
values (...)

set @id_1 = select scope_identity()

insert into table_2 (...) 
values (...)

set @id_2 = select scope_identity()
```

For sure `@id_1` gets the last inserted id of `table_1`. The question is, does `@id_2` get the last inserted id of `table_2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure - if both `table_1` and `table_2` for an `identity` column - **why not**??

But please use this syntax:

```
select @id_1 = scope_identity()
```

No need for both a `set` and a `select`...

Comment: May I know what's the difference in performance? or what's the difference in general when using `set` and `select` and `select @id_1 = scope_idenity()` ?

Comment: @darogo: no performance difference - just a thing of clarity and no using unnecessary additional keywords....